# Use fields Owner and Tag on Azure Pipelines test report

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pytest, nunit

I'm using pytest-nunit to generate a test report in azure pipelines. and I noticed two fields (Owner and Tags) that I would like to use, but couldn't find any documentation.
Any idea on what azure looks on the report to populate this fields?

[image: an image with the filds currently blank]

I already tried using the pytest-nunit fixture `record_nunit_property`, but seems that azure ignored the properties added this way.

Comment: We do not have enough information to provide you an answer. Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).